# Fetch all available application for a specific google developer account with Google play API service?

Tags: android, ruby, google-api

with the Google Play API there is a way to fetch all available application for a specific google developer account ?

Comment: The link you are using is used to manage (like delete, update, add) APK specific localized strings that to after authorization with the account through which APK is published. As of now, I think there is no official API to get what you need :)

Comment: i can't fetch all available application for a specific account